# The parameter is null when FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set in PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-12

Currently, I was trying to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE for PendingIntent.getActivity(For android 12). However, it doesn't work (The parameter set in PendingIntent is null). If I replace it with FLAG_MUTABLE, it does work.

PendingIntent.getService(activity, 0, myServiceRequestIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

According to google docs, FLAG_IMMUTABLE is recommended way to pass pending intent.
Are there some conditions or situations where you cannot use FLAG_IMMUTABLE? If there are examples of tips that will be really helpful

The additional_extra extra is null when I pass it back in the following format.

val pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra("pending_intent")

```
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra("additional_extra", "test")
        }

        pendingIntent?.send(this, 0, intent)
```

Comment: Your question asks about `PendingIntent.getActivity()` but your code example is for `PendingIntent.getService()`. Also, what do you mean by "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? What do you expect to happen? What do you see? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some conditions or situations where you cannot use FLAG_IMMUTABLE?

According to: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#CreateImmutablePendingIntents

> ...certain use cases require mutable `PendingIntent` objects instead

I have found for instance that [BLE scanning using a PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and Activity Recognition updates to an IntentService both require FLAG_MUTABLE, otherwise the delivered intents are essentially empty.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue after changing intents to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | FLAG_IMMUTABLE` as per [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag). Then actually noticed that [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent) says specify either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE. First one didn't work for me to pass data, switching to FLAG_MUTABLE seems to work:

```
    val flags = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        else -> PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, someId.toInt(), intent, flags)
```