# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, exoplayer2.x, android-12

App crashes at runtime with the following error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maa.abc: Targeting
> S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or
> FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if
> it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
> at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
> at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createBroadcastIntent(PlayerNotificationManager.java:1373)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createPlaybackActions(PlayerNotificationManager.java:1329)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.(PlayerNotificationManager.java:643)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.(PlayerNotificationManager.java:529)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(PlayerNotificationManager.java:456)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(PlayerNotificationManager.java:417)

I tried all solutions available but the app still crashing on Android 12.

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(@NonNull Player player) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(service, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

 }
```

Comment: But my project didn't use PeningIntent, also cause the error!

Answer (score 75):

If using java or react-native then paste this inside app/build.gradle

```js
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
}
```

If using Kotlin then use this

```js
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

and if anybody still facing the crash issue for android 12 then make sure you add following in AndroidMenifest.xml

```js
 <activity 
   ...
   android:exported="true" // in most cases it is true but based on requirements it can be false also   
>   


   // If using react-native push notifications then make sure to add into it also

 <receiver   
android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="true">
 
   //  Similarly
 
 <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="true">
```

Comment: Even after adding the FLAG_IMMUTABLE and the dependency, I'm still getting the error on some Samsung devices:

Galaxy Note20 5G, 
Galaxy S20 FE 5G, 
and others.

Comment: Yes I also found it on Samsung and HTC devices. I will post solutions once I solve it

Comment: Please take a look at this comment https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33375#issuecomment-1080979397

Comment: Thanks @HamzaHmem is this working  for you ? did you try?

Comment: @HaryanviDeveloper I've tried your solution and it's worked. However, there is a fix developed by the react native core team itself but it will be released with the 0.69 version.

Comment: @HamzaHmem thanks could you please tell me where exactly we need to change?

Answer (score 25):

Check and update the dependency version of exoplayer to the latest one

`android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` previously used to return

```
@Nullable
@Override
private static PendingIntent createBroadcastIntent(
    String action, Context context, int instanceId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action).setPackage(context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INSTANCE_ID, instanceId);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, instanceId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }
```

If you observe carefully PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE is missing here in the above snippet

It has now been updated to return the following

```
@Nullable
@Override
private static PendingIntent createBroadcastIntent(
      String action, Context context, int instanceId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action).setPackage(context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INSTANCE_ID, instanceId);

    int pendingFlags;
    if (Util.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      pendingFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
    } else {
      pendingFlags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
    }

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, instanceId, intent, pendingFlags);
  }
```

Comment: Cool, but why should we check the version 23 and above when the error message is "Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)"

Comment: @Tarek PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE is not present in API below 23. The error message is because android has made it mandatory to add PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMUTABLE to all the pending intents from API 31(S) onwards

Comment: Noticed that use of the `Util.SDK_INT` constants might not be very portable for most projects, and so would recommend use of the android "official" `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` variants.

Comment: what is flutter kotlin version of code?

Answer (score 14):

In my case for read tags using the foreground delivery system, its works..

If you let your app to run in android 12, use the following:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
          0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}else {
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
      0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, but i had to specify only FLAG_MUTABLE instead of both

Comment: Too much copy/paste. Use flags variable instead. and the pendingIntent creation will be one command instead of two.

Comment: Or ternary operator pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
          0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(
   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 10):

For Future reference

add    `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1` to `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
}
```

add `| PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to line where you define PendingIntent

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

Comment: worth noting that if you have issues with metro this fixes the problem by setting the flag. Only good answer in this thread.

Answer (score 6):

Solution for Kotlin, juste add this flag if you are with API M

```
val flags = when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M -> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            else -> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }
val toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, providerIntent, flags)
```

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by adding in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I face the same issue, and as instructed in most of the answers I have updated my dependency as follows.

```
dependencies {
  /* Use either Kotlin or Java dependency as per your project */

  // ...
  /* Android Arch Component Work Manager for Kotlin */
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' 


  //...
  /* Android Arch Component Work Manager for Java */
  def work_version = "2.7.1"
  implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
  // optional - Test helpers
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"
}
```

But adding only the above didn’t sort out my issue and the app still got crashed.

So I switched off the Android Lint: Missing Pending Intent Mutability, Find the steps below to switch off.

**Switching off Pending Intent Mutability**

Go to the Search option and search "PendingIntent" and you will receive a window as shown below.

[image: Android Studio Search window]

Switch of the Android Lint: Missing Pending Intent Mutability and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on Android 12 for Url_Launcher. after adding this to `build.gradle` file, I solved my problem.

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

Comment: This line of code not working for me. The error remains the same!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding below in the ...android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0-alpha01'
```

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4083#issue-1119280606

Answer (score 0):

If the **Chuck** library produces your problem, you won't be able to using it after updating the SDK version. You can easily replace it with **Chucker** (Chuck's fork): https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck/issues/101#issuecomment-869119599.

Answer (score 0):

A few things, make sure you are using JDK 11, second delete that .gradle folder inside the android folder, then follow along on this wonderful answer [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465890/my-react-native-app-crash-after-update-target-sdk-version-31).

Try after doing gradle clean