# React-native expo-facebook 12.2.0 with Android 31 error at login: FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE must be specified

Tags: android, react-native, expo, facebook-javascript-sdk, expo-facebook

Upgrading Android version to 31 I get a new error with expo-facebook:

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
```

I tried to add `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'` as specified in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag) but I still get the error.

What other solution than downgrading the target Android version do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
.....
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.3.0'

}
```

And then look for these files and lines, and modify them too.

```
/node_modules/expo-notifications/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/notifications/service/NotificationsService.kt
```

Line (463): `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Modify to: `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

```
/node_modules/expo-task-manager/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/taskManager/TaskManagerUtils.java
```

Line (463): `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Modify to: `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

```
/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/services/LocationTaskService.java
```

Line (463): `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Modify to: `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

Then just run the command for installation on the simulator or device that will work 100%

Comment: Please, make separate blocks of code