# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.appname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

My react native app is crashing on start for android 12 (for some user). I have received error report on crashlytics dashboard. I can't also reproduce the error since app running on my android device just fine. This is the error in crashlytics dashbord. looks like problem with a third party library react-native-firebase but not sure how to fix this, anyone here facing the same problem ?

error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.halkhata: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:465)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:451)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:415)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createContentIntent(CommonNotificationBuilder.java:26)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(CommonNotificationBuilder.java:69)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.CommonNotificationBuilder.createNotificationInfo(CommonNotificationBuilder.java:34)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.DisplayNotification.handleNotification(DisplayNotification.java:28)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(FirebaseMessagingService.java:36)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(FirebaseMessagingService.java:130)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(FirebaseMessagingService.java:12)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(FirebaseMessagingService.java:89)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(EnhancedIntentService.java:1)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(EnhancedIntentService.java:6)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(zza.java:6)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG\_IMMUTABLE or FLAG\_MUTABLE be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag)