# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the below error for my xamarin forms application on version 31 and above.

> com.mycompanyname.myappname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> [ImeFocusController] onWindowFocus: DecorView@74e918a[MainActivity] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_RESIZE|IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION
> [ImeFocusController] Restarting due to isRestartOnNextWindowFocus as true
> [ImeFocusController] onViewFocusChanged, view=DecorView@74e918a[MainActivity], mServedView=null
> [ImeFocusController] checkFocus: view=null next=DecorView@74e918a[MainActivity] force=true package=
> The thread 0xb has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
> [AndroidRuntime] Process: com.mycompanyname.myappname, PID: 7466
> [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.mycompanyname.myappname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> [AndroidRuntime] Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzd(Unknown Source:18)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source:229)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:0)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source:41)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzj.getToken(Unknown Source:56)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source:10)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzcfy(Unknown Source:4)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:148)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:122)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> Thread started:  #12
> **Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:** 'com.mycompanyname.myappname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.'

I am using pendingIntent on my project for FCM.

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

I tried `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` and `FLAG_MUTABLE` instead of `OneShot`, but app is breaking. I commented the entire code related to FCM, but after that also, the app is breaking with the same issue.

I tried updating the FCM related Packages, that also don't work.  Any other olutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG\_IMMUTABLE or FLAG\_MUTABLE be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag)

Comment: @KenWhite I am facing the issue on the xamarin platform; the suggested one is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recheck your problem by following steps as follows:

1.try to update all your firebase libraries and google libraries to the latest;

2.try to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to your pending intents.

Here is an example :

```
        var intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));

        var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
            ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable
            : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;
        var pendingActivityIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, requestCode, intent, pendingIntentFlags);
```

For more information, you can check this link: [PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

3.check if you have installed the latest nuget [Xamarin.AndroidX.work.runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime/);

Comment: `Xamarin.AndroidX.work.runtime` Is this package needed only for android platform or the entire solution?

Comment: `Xamarin.AndroidX.work.runtime` is needed for  android platform. You can try to install it only on the android project for your xamarin forms app.

Comment: I have add FLAG_IMMUTABLE and Update work.runtime but still no luck. any idea?