# My app throws this error: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified... How can I solve it?

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing the above error on my app, developed with React Native and builded with Expo and gradlew. Tried some of the solutions available on internet, like:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

But it doesn´t work...

Tried a bunch of solutions, some displayed on this topic: [Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag)

Comment: Include the full stack trace. That's will tell you and us what is actually creating the PendingIntent

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase to handle custom/data messages for notifications, please check android source code for any pending intent calls.